Facing slowness issue when executing automation tests on chrome browser on macbook m1 pro
Automation tests when executed on chrome browser on macbook m1 pro is very slow, it is slow 2-3 times slow compare to any other windows machines. Does anyone have any idea or solution about it?
I tried with using multiple chromedrivers and chrome versions to see if issue is with latest chrome or not.
Also I tried to use chrome for testing browser from chromedriver download site, It also didn't work.
Tried with firefox and it works fine with firefox.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
